# Selecting a marker by default using Google-Maps-for-Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have a map with markers, and I need to select one marker by dafault, like shown below. Is this possible using [**gmaps4rails**](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)?

[image]

Ok here is what worked for me:

```
      Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
        if (Gmaps.map.markers.length == 1) {
         //only one marker, choose the zoom level you expect
         setTimeout(function() { Gmaps.map.serviceObject.setZoom(15);}, 50);
        }
        else{
         //more than one marker, let's auto_zoom
         Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = true;
         Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
        }
        // focus on first marker
        marker = Gmaps.map.markers[0]
        setTimeout(function() { google.maps.event.trigger(marker.serviceObject, 'click') }, 250);  
      }
```

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: gmaps4rails (1.5.6) but I could upgrade if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.5.6 is not that convenient, but:

First get your marker (should live in `Gmaps.map.markers`)

Then:

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(marker.serviceObject, 'click')
```

Comment: (I really recommend you move to v2 whenever you can)

Comment: How would I accomplish this in v2? Are there any known gem conflicts with v2?

Comment: v2 is quite different, details are in the wiki

Comment: Does it tell you how to have a marker selected? Can you point me there?

Comment: you have a solution for 1.5.6, ask again if you migrate no?

Comment: I want to know if there are any gem conflicts that you are aware of please?

Comment: v2 is quite different, details are in the wiki

Comment: I have edited my question, please help. I don't have time to read wiki now sorry